# Significato di "malcavato" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Dopo una breve esitazione fra Albina e Costanza la sua scelta era caduta su Albina, non perché fosse rimasto colpito dalla sua bellezza severa, piuttosto il fulgore dell’altra gli era sembrato promettere sospiri e patimenti, mentre a lui premeva di risanare quanto prima le finanze di famiglia. Ad Albina non era parso vero che un barone la preferisse alla sorella, ed era pronta a giurargli fedeltà eterna, anche se Aurelio era corto e **malcavato** e per guardarla negli occhi doveva starsene col naso all’insú.

Da una ricerca su Google, ho visto che "malcavato" può anche essere scritto "mal cavato". Cercando il significato del [verbo "cavare" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cavare), credo che l'espressione faccia in qualche modo riferimento all'accezione numero 2, cioè, "ricavare", soprattutto nel senso di "ottenere". Tuttavia, non so se abbia del tutto senso affermare che Aurelio era "ottenuto male", quindi immagino ci sia una maniera migliore di spiegare il significato di "malcavato" nel brano sopra citato. Me la sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Probabilmente dal dialetto lucano: ***Corto e mal cavat*** (italianizzazione del detto locale con cui si usava indicare una persona di bassa statura ma furba e peperina, per similitudine ai cavatelli corti e “cavati” male, quindi di difficile cottura e non facilmente digeribili). http://www.lucanomagazine.it/2014/12/corto-e-mal-cavat-avigliano-la-clermont-ferrand-lucana/

Comment: @Gio La casella per le risposte è più in basso.

Comment: @Gio:  Ho visto che appare anche [qui](http://web.tiscali.it/miglionico/proverb.htm) e [qui](http://letsfindthebar.blogspot.com/2009/05/proverbi.html?m=1). Denis ha ragione, però: potresti cercare di scrivere una risposta?

Comment: Io credo faccia riferimento alla nascita. "Malcavato" = "Mal cavato" = "venuto fuori male", "uscito male" (dal grembo) per indicare il fatto che ha un difetto fisico.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Quindi, il significato potrebbe essere più o meno quello di "malfatto"?

Comment: @Charo secondo me è così (opinione personale, non conosco l'origine dell'espressione).

Comment: Appare  [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=_T0dBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&lpg=PT24&dq=%22mal+cavato%22+%22mal+fatto%22&source=bl&ots=hV4gsLzN6e&sig=ACfU3U00ZRsvPW3JlSsvtlWM35Xm0WDTKA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwmOT0pa7oAhWk3eAKHcvmA5UQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22mal%20cavato%22%20%22mal%20fatto%22&f=false) in versione siciliana e anche [qui](http://www.altadauniaaltosalento.it/showthread.php?4142-P%EBcc%EBninn%EB-e-mal%EB-cavat%EB).

Comment: @Charo Credo che l'interpretazione di Gio sia decisamente la più appropriata.

Comment: Ottimo, @AntonioMariaDiMauro. Potresti scrivere una risposta? Mi piacerebbe tantissimo...

Comment: @Charo Purtroppo non posso rispondere perché il dialetto parlato nel mio paese -Maratea- è profondamente diverso da quelli parlati in altre zone della Lucania: esso è difatti molto più simile al Calabrese o per certi aspetti al Ciletano o addirittura al Siciliano, poiché infatti il mio paese  confina a sud colla Calabria e a nord col basso Cilento, il quale in passato per via della sua posizione geografica era frequentato da pescatori siciliani che hanno discretamente influenzato lessico e  fonetica dei dialetti parlati in tale area.

Comment: @Charo Ad ogni modo posso sostenere con discreta certezza che la risposta di Gio è corretta, poiché infatti mi sembra di aver sentito tale espressione da un amico di mio padre il quale puta caso è originario di Avigliano, il paese indicato nell'articolo allegato alla risposta di Gio.

Comment: Grazie, @AntonioMariaDiMauro: infatti la faccenda narrata nel romanzo si svolge a Grottole.

Comment: @Charo Prego, di nulla!